# Obtener el valor máximo de dos columnas

Tags: sql, oracle

tengo la duda de cómo realizar esta consulta de la forma más eficiente. 
Existe una tabla `PRODUCTO`, que contiene su identificador. Y una tabla `PRODUCTOESTADO`, donde se almacena el historial de estados de ese producto.

El modelo sería asi:

```
PRODUCTO (IDPRODUCTO(PK));

PRODUCTOESTADO (IDPRODUCTOESTADO(PK), TIPOESTADO, FECHACAMBIOESTADO, IDPRODUCTO(FK));
```

`TIPOESTADO`: Almacena el estado del producto (estado 1, estado 2...)

`FECHACAMBIOESTADO`: Almacena la fecha en la que se realiza el cambio de estado.

Lo que necesito obtener es el último estado de cada producto.

La forma en la que lo obtengo es la siguiente:

```
SELECT PRODUCTOESTADO.IDPRODUCTO, PRODUCTOESTADO.TIPOESTADO
  FROM PRODUCTOESTADO
       INNER JOIN
          (SELECT PRODUCTOESTADO.IDPRODUCTO, MAX (PRODUCTOESTADO.FECHACAMIOESTADO) FECHACAMIOESTADOMAXIMA
               FROM PRODUCTOESTADO
           GROUP BY PRODUCTOESTADO.IDPRODUCTO) TABLA_ULTIMOESTADO
       ON PRODUCTOESTADO.IDPRODUCTO = TABLA_ULTIMOESTADO.IDPRODUCTO AND PRODUCTOESTADO.FECHACAMIOESTADO = TABLA_ULTIMOESTADO.FECHACAMIOESTADOMAXIMA;
```

Es decir, obtengo de cada producto su máxima fecha, y luego sobre ese resultado obtengo el estado en el que está.
Lo que quiero saber es que si esta es una buena forma de hacerlo o hay alguna forma mucho más simple.

Comment: Hola Dani, como sugerencia, usa el *backtick* ( ` ) en vez de el asterisco para resaltar nombres de tablas, columnas, variables... es para dar formato de codigo pero en un ambito de palabra o frase

Comment: Ah perfecto. Gracias

Comment: Creo que seria correcta tu solución. Yo lo hubiera hecho igual.

Comment: Otra opción es usar opciones de ranking, aunque en términos de rendimiento no se cual de las dos formas es mejor, pero puede que ayude en la claridad de la sql.

Answer (score 2):

Es casi seguro que la forma más eficiente de efectuar esta consulta es usando la función ventana `row_number()`. Te tocará hacer la comparación de rendimiento para confirmarlo, pero usando `row_number()`, Oracle no necesita recorrer la tabla `productoestado` más de una vez:

```
select idproducto, tipoestado
  from (select idproducto, 
               tipoestado,
               row_number() over (
                   partition by idproducto
                       order by fechacambioestado desc) as rn
          from productoestado)
 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría así:

```
SELECT idproducto
     , tipoestado
  FROM productoestado exterior
 WHERE not exists
          (SELECT 1
             FROM productoestado interior
            WHERE interior.idproducto = exterior.idproducto
              and interior.fechacambioestado > exterior.fechacambioestado);
```

O, alternativamente (y suponiendo que idproductoestado sea secuencial):

```
SELECT idproducto
     , tipoestado
  FROM productoestado
 WHERE idproductoestado in
          (SELECT max(interior.idproductoestado)
             FROM productoestado interior
            GROUP BY interior.idproducto);
```

Por otro lado, no me parece descabellada tu solución.

Answer (score 0):

EL campo que indica el último cambio es la fecha, así que yo lo haría así:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM productoestado p
 WHERE p.fechacambioestado = (SELECT max(fechacambioestado)
                            FROM productoestado 
                            where idproducto = p.idproducto
                            and IDPRODUCTOESTADO = p.IDPRODUCTOESTADO);
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

creo que para mi es poco tarde responder, hace poco me registre, pero lo que entiendo es que se quiere es comparar varias columnas y una vez comparada, me saque el valor maximo, si es asi lo voy a colocar con un ejemplo mio que hace eso

```
   SELECT 
       A.ITEM_NAME AS COMPLETION, 
       A.START_DATETIME AS START_DATETIME, 
       A.ACT_GAS_VOL AS ACT_GAS_VOL, 
       A.ACT_OIL_VOL AS ACT_OIL_VOL, 
       A.ACT_WAT_VOL AS ACT_WAT_VOL,
       (SELECT MAX(ST.valor) 
          FROM 
                 (
                         SELECT A.ACT_GAS_VOL AS valor
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT A.ACT_OIL_VOL AS valor
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT A.ACT_WAT_VOL AS valor

                ) AS ST
            ) maximo
   FROM VT_TOTALS_DAY_en_US A
```